# Using Dynamic Content to Retrieve Files in ADF CopyData

Tags: wildcard, azure-data-factory

I am trying to run a Copy Data pipeline that processes daily file feeds from an SFTP server. The naming of those files are:

1. `abc_2021_07_21_010340.csv`
2. `abc_2021_07_20_010441.csv`
3. `abc_2021_07_19_020540.csv`
   ...and so on

where

- `abc` is the prefix;
- `_2021_07_20_` is the year, month, and day of the daily file;
- `010340` is the timestamp where the file was generated

How do I correctly write the wildcard syntax based on today's date? I have tried the following but it did not worked:

`@{concat('abc_', formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyy_MM_dd'),'*.csv')}`

***EDIT on 13-07-2021***

Removing the curly braces, but was shown with a `No preview data to show` message.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concat function looks correct, but I don't think you need the curly braces. This example was produced with the expression builder and does not contain them:

[image]

Are the files in a Folder on the SFTP server? If so, that needs to be specified as well.

Comment: thanks for the input. However, removing the curly braces still did not work. There was no error message but was left with `No preview data to show` when trying to preview the data.

Comment: What about the SFTP Folder? Even if you specify it in the Dataset, I'm pretty sure you have to declare it when you use the Wildcard option.

Comment: I still think the syntax is not working, I have tried changing it to `@concat('abc_', formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyy_MM_dd'),'_010340.csv')`, without the `*` wildcard and I am able to preview the data.

Comment: It could be a bug in the Copy activity Preview with wildcard. Have you tried running the process rather than previewing the data?